# With Glue Version 4.0 union in spark.sql is taking too long to execute

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

My glue job handles a long query which has many unions. When I run it with Glue Version 3.0 it works fine but when I change it to Glue Version 4.0 and run it takes forever to execute. Can you please suggest if I have to add anything to the spark configuration ?